# What happened to removing items from realm.io? RealmException "Removing object is not supported."?

Tags: android, database, realm

I am trying to delete the last Object from the Realm.io database based on a query, like so:

```
    Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(this);
    final RealmResults<RealmCustomLocation> databaseLocations = realm.where(RealmCustomLocation.class).findAllSorted("timeStamp", RealmResults.SORT_ORDER_DESCENDING);
    if(databaseLocations.size() >= 4){
        realm.beginTransaction();
        databaseLocations.removeLast();
        realm.commitTransaction();
    }
```

This is exactly like what is written at the [Realm.io instructions](http://realm.io/docs/java/0.77.0/#deletion) about deletion:

```
realm.beginTransaction();
result.removeLast();
realm.commitTransaction()
```

But when I execute the code it always breaks with a RealmException

```
io.realm.exceptions.RealmException: Removing object is not supported.
```

Then I looked at the source code of RealmResults.java and I find this:
[image]
So no wonder it keeps crashing, removeLast() does nothing, only throw an error!

So my question is: **How can I remove an object from the database then?!**

I am using realm.io 0.77 (compile 'io.realm:realm-android:0.77.0') on Android.

I appreciate your help on this!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have contacted Realm.io support, awaiting an answer. For the meantime:

```
RealmCustomLocation location = databaseLocations.get(databaseLocations.size() - 1);
location.removeFromRealm();
```

works equivalent to

```
databaseLocations.removeLast()
```

so it can be used as a workaround.

Edit: Support told me that they are fixing it for future versions and recommended to use the workaround I posted for in the mean time.

Comment: any word from Realm.io?

Comment: No updates yet, either they have not fixed the issue or they forgot about my request. I moved to DBFlow for my database needs, because in my opinion Realm is not mature enough at the moment

Comment: Just ran into this myself. I can't believe they haven't at least updated the documentation on how to delete something.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete all objects, then I would create a while loop like this:

```
while (location.size() > 0) {
    location.removeLast();
}
```